Does Windows Terminal not have alternate screen?
Forgive me if I have the terminology wrong.  I've used PuTTy for years to ssh into various boxes, and then use neovim to edit files.  Normally when I exit neovim, whatever was visible on the screen before entering it is still there.  With Windows Terminal, I get given a blank screen instead.
In most regards Windows Terminal seems much better than PuTTy, but search as I might, I cannot find a setting or a solution to this. Lots of people swear by WT as being a great PuTTy alternative.

Windows Terminal has had alternate screen (\e[?1049h) support starting with version v1.14.
To test it, run echo "$([char]0x1B)[?1049h" in PowerShell or printf '\e[?1049h' in Bash. Doing the same with 1049l will switch back to regular mode.


It's not a good idea set TERM from .bashrc without first checking that the new value is suitable for the terminal. While many terminals are cross-compatible to an extent (most of them implementing the same DEC & xterm extensions), the specific TERM values for one terminal may be too different from another – such as putty-256color for PuTTY being just a little bit too different from what Windows Terminal implements.
(Windows Terminal has its own terminfo DB entry: TERM=ms-terminal; however it's likely that the entry will be a little outdated, as terminfo doesn't move nearly as fast as WT development.)
Unfortunately, there is no good way to check from .bashrc whether putty-256color is suitable or not. Instead, if you're using PuTTY you should set the default TERM value it sends to server and save as "Default Session".
But at least, if you want to use "xterm-256color", don't blindly do TERM=xterm-256color – at least put it within an if [ $TERM = ... ]. For example:
if [[ $TERM == @(xterm|screen|tmux) ]]; then
    TERM="$TERM-256color"
fi


Great.  I'm on v1.21.  Can you please explain to me how I enable this feature, since it appears to be disabled by default?

No, it's enabled by default. I don't think there even is a setting to disable it.

I'm confused.  So I should be seeing the same behaviour when exiting vi/vim/neovim in WT as I do in PuTTy?  But I'm not, in WT I get a blank screen.

That likely depends on whether you're running vi/vim/neovim locally or over SSH (and then – over which SSH client), and possibly on whether the SSH session has the right $TERM... Run an echo "$([char]0x1B)[?1049h" in PowerShell or printf '\e[?1049h' in Bash to check whether it works locally and then over SSH.

Thanks you for bearing with me, I've never used WT before today.  I created a new profile to connect to my server, over SSH.  When I run that echo command locally in powershell, it does indeed clear the screen.  When I run the print command in my bash shell in my SSH session, it also clears the screen.  Does this tell you anything useful?

If I echo $TERM in my SSH session I get putty-256color - I'm guessing this points to the issue?  In my neovim init.lua I have vim.opt.termguicolors = true, but whether I have that or not doesn't seem to change the output of echo $TERM (either from bash or from :! in neovim, regardless of whether I have that opt line or not.

It clears the screen because it switches to the alternate screen. Doing the same with 1049l would switch back. That $TERM definitely doesn't sound right – although it might still be "close enough" (after all, most PuTTY sessions do the opposite and claim to be xterm), but I wouldn't be surprised if it was the issue. Generally $TERM is set by the local terminal and sent as a parameter via SSH, but WT doesn't do it (leaving it to the SSH client to make something up), so it's likely your SSH client that invents the wrong TERM value, or maybe the server's .bashrc overrides it with the wrong one.

Ta, I'm not with it now but I'll investigate my sshd_confog when I get home to see if there's anything useful in there

Thank you.  It was set in my .bashrc file.  Changed it from putty-256color to xterm-256color and all is well again.  You're a trooper!

as a point of nitpicking: TERM=ms-terminal is not something that the Windows Terminal team owns or maintains. Someone else wrote that some years ago (when WT was still in early preview). It's vastly out of date, and I'm not sure where it's actually included.
WT does its absolute best to emulate xterm-256color. That's effectively the TERM we would use. For all intents and purposes, treat WT as xterm-256color
